# How to get current battery percentage?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, batterylevel

I'm creating a battery monitor application, and I'm trying to display the current battery percentage.  I have a broadcastreceiver, that is listening for...

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" />
```

In the receiver I have the following code.

```
int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

currentBatteryLevel = level / (float) scale;

Toast.makeText(context, "Current battery level: " + Float.toString(currentBatteryLevel) + "%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

For some reason, the result is always `Current battery level: 1.0%`...Where am I going wrong?

Edit:

Reciever is registered in the manifest as...

```
<receiver android:name=".PowerMonitorReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and my receiver is...

package com.garciaericn.t2d;

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PowerMonitorReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "PowerMonitorReceiver.TAG";
    private float currentBatteryLevel;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



        // Obtain action from intent to check which broadcast is being received
        String action = intent.getAction();

        // Perform action according to type
        switch (action) {
            case (Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED): {
                Log.i(TAG, "Battery has changed");

                int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
                int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

                currentBatteryLevel = (level * 100) / (float) scale;

                Toast.makeText(context, "Current battery level: " + Float.toString(currentBatteryLevel) + "%" + " level: " + level + " scale: " + scale, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                break;
            }
            case (Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED): {
                Log.i(TAG, "Power connected");

                int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
                boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING || status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

                int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
                boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
                boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

                String chargingType = null;

                if (usbCharge) {
                    chargingType = "USB";
                } else if (acCharge) {
                    chargingType = "AC Power";
                }

                if (isCharging && chargingType != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Device is charging via: " + chargingType, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Device is charging.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            }
            case (Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED): {
                Log.i(TAG, "Power disconnected");
                Toast.makeText(context, "Power Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            case (Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW): {
                Log.i(TAG, "Battery low");
                Toast.makeText(context, "Battery low", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            case (Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY): {
                Log.i(TAG, "Battery Okay");
                Toast.makeText(context, "Battery Okay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your receiver and where you register it

Answer (score 6):

I think it's pretty late but the solution is quite simple. According to [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html#CurrentLevel), you will not receive updates for BATTERY_CHANGED if you have registered the broadcast receiver in xml since it's a sticky broadcast.

You need to register Broadcastreceivers in your java program as below.

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);

int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
float batteryPct = (level * 100) / (float)scale;
```

NOTE: Even though you pass "null" as the receiver you can still receive all the required battery data. You can also pass a Receiver class instead of "null" for continuous monitoring but beware this will drain your device battery as these broadcasts are thrown very often.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are listening for multiple broadcasts, you need to determine which type of broadcast it is.

```
String action = intent.getAction();

if(action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)){
    int level   = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
    int scale   = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, 100);
    int percent = (level*100)/scale;

    Toast.makeText(context, "Current battery level: " + percent + "%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helps.  This fires and work for all the other triggers.  But the `BATTERY_CHANGED` is never called.  I've tried on a physical device and Genymotion emulator simulating different events with the battery.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean acCharge = false;
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
        status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

if(isCharging){
        chargePercentage = 
        batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    }
```

The chargePercentage variable will give you the current charge percentage.